# Vectorization of logical expressions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a 1 x n array. I would like to check whether each element is greater than its five consequent elements. That is, `i>i+1 & i>i+2 & i>i+3 & i>i+4 & i>i+5`.

How would I do this without any loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
idx = 1:numel(x)-5;
I = x(idx) > x(idx+1) & x(idx) > x(idx+2) & x(idx) > x(idx+3) & x(idx) > x(idx+4) & x(idx) > x(idx+5)
```

Note that this doesn't really handle the last 5 elements of x because it depends on what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this vectorized solution:

```
N = 5;                                        %# number of consequent values
idx = hankel(2:N+1, N+1:numel(x));            %# indices of sliding windows
y = all( bsxfun(@gt, x(1:end-N), x(idx)) )    %# comparison
```

The result is a boolean vector, where `y(i)` indicates whether `x(i)` is greater than all of `x(i+1), x(i+2), ..., x(i+N)`